# In google contacts where is the contact for me?

Tags: contacts, htc-desire, gmail, htc-sense

I'm not sure if it matters but my phone has 'HTC sense'.

I have all my contacts sync'd with my google account.

I have a normal contact called "me" in my google contacts that through various merging has accumulated all my contact details.

However on the phone that shows up as a normal contact called "me" rather than going into the special "my contact card" thing.

I would like to fix this, but preferably without having to copy all the stuff over manually.

Comment: As per Bob's answer below, "My Contact Card" is a special HTC thing and isn't a normal contact.  What's wrong with using the "Me" contact?  Just ignore "My contact Card".

Answer (score 1):

The contact record for you I assume just has your name.  If you link the two (top right corner when editing a contact) it will pull all of the information in.  On the down side it will eliminate the "Me" entry.  At least that's how I remember it working when I went through this.  My Wife just left with my phone for the evening...

Comment: There is no entry in google contacts with my name, only the me one.

Comment: Also on the phone the the "my contact card" doesn't have the link option. And if I select link on the "me" contact I can't find the "my contact card".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Me" is a reserved name in the Android contacts app.  Try renaming your "Me" contact in your Google account and then see what happens in Android after syncing contacts again.

Answer (score 1):

Mine too, also HTC Sense. My "My Contact Card" isn't called 'me' but rather has my name - it's linked to my facebook account which I think happened during set up. The HTC site says this about "My Contact Card"...

"My contact card provides a convenient way to store your personal contact information so that you can easily send it via MMS. In addition, you can log in to your Facebook and Flickr accounts to receive notifications of your contacts' updates and events. On the All tab of the People screen, tap Me, and then tap  here [??] to edit contact."

Anyway the result is that my phone has a perfectly good contact record for me from Google Mail/Talk (with my various phone numbers, email and physical address) and another useless one sucked in from Facebook - it doesn't seem possible to link my personal Google contact record to my Facebook Record or to delete the 'My Contact Card'. That's a bit of a mess really, shame as the rest of the gmail/facebook integration is very good.