# Use existing contact for "Me" in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Nexus S has just been updated to Ice Cream Sandwich, and I notice that in contacts there is a new space for "me". Is there a way to assign the existing ordinary contact  for me (a contact with my name and details that I sometimes use for sharing with people, and sync with Picasa Photos etc.) to this slot?

It seems related to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3035/1486), but that is about the similar HTC specific feature found on some phones.

Comment: Same problem here. For some weird reason, it is also not possible to first create the new 'me' and then ***merge*** it with the old contact.

Answer (score 29):

After trying forever (the "me" profile was never synced and could not be merged), this worked for me:

Install the Google+ app.
Set it to sync contacts.
Open your contacts again; your contact will now be set as "my profile".
Seriously.

source: https://makandracards.com/arne/7763-android-4-0-how-to-set-me-contact-to-your-existing-contact

Comment: How exactly do you Sync contacts? When used in a straightforward way, it didn't helped on my Moto G 2nd gen XT1079 -- but maybe I was doing something wrong...

Comment: Nice. After waiting a few minutes for the contact sync to happen, the Me contact was updated as you mentioned (Android 4.4.4).

Comment: This is the dumbest thing, but it works. Thank you. Android 5.1.1.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really work, it "just" syncs you data from you Google+ account into your "me" profile. The result is not the same

Answer (score 11):

I searched for days and apparently the answer is : no you can't. The "me" contact can be synced with third party apps ( Google+, HaxSync... ) but for an unknow reason you can't merge a "normal" contact with the "me" contact... Maybe with Jelly Bean the problem will be solved.

Comment: As a reference, Jelly Bean didn't "change" this.

Comment: Still don't see it on 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same as "existing contact", but upon installing the Google+ app the phone synced the "Me" contact with everything in my Google+ profile.  This was on my Galaxy Nexus on ICS 4.0.4 with the latest Google+ app.

Answer (score 2):

1. backup
2. Hard reset your phone to clear out all contact info (CAUTION - this will also wipe all settings, download apps, etc. on your phone - also be sure to avoid wiping your SD card)
3. **BEFORE** signing into Google, Facebook etc. or anything else that may attempt to link to your "me" contact, first reinstall your contacts including your "regular" contact card.
4. **BEFORE** signing into Google, Facebook etc. click the "me" contact on phone and (if you haven't done anything else yet that might affect the "me" contact) then on this first time opening the "me" card your phone will ask if you want to "edit" or "link" the "me" contact to an existing contact on your phone and choose the "link" option. (mine did this automatically, but otherwise you may need to choose "menu" option once your "me" contact is open)

Comment: This is completely nonsense, the need to reset totally a phone merely to edit a contact info. It smells to me as commercial war between Samsung and Google over user information.

Answer (score -1):

Pull up the contact, open the menu and choose edit, then open the menu on that screen and choose join. You can then choose a contact to merge it with.

Comment: Join is not an available option on the "me" contact :(

Comment: Oh. Hm. That's odd. Can you do anything with it from your Google account, accessed through a web browser?