# How to edit the "ME" contact?

Tags: contacts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

On my Galaxy Nexus running (stock, non-rooted) ICS, there is a contact entry for "ME".

This is different from the contact entry farther down the list with my actual name on it.
And the contact for "ME" actually contains some incorrect information. Some non-existent email addresses, etc. I don't even know where these came from, as they aren't anywhere in my contacts lists nor in my G+ profile.

When I try to edit "ME", it does not give me the option to modify the email addresses. 
And it also doesn't let me Join this contact with the other instance of myself.

How can I edit this "ME" contact to show correct information?
Or can I somehow delete it and choose a different contact to represent ME?

Comment: I looks to me that a lot of this info comes from your Google+ profile. I'm looking into it further.

Comment: Possible **duplicate** of: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17159/4168

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like the majority of the outdated information I'm seeing in my entry came from my Google+ profile. I've since edited that, and "refreshed" in the Google+ app, but the information remains. Annoying, to say the least. I'm inclined to call this a bug.

Comment: In my case, this info was never in my Google+ profile. The only connection that I can see is that one of the email addresses used to (but doesn't anymore) forward to my gmail address. But hopefully this is something that they can address in an ICS update, either to make the "ME" contact more editable or more refreshable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also had the same problem and it took me 2 days to fix this

Try going to contacts.google.com.

Find your profile (should have your gmail on email address)

Re-add the faulty data (it was an old phone number in my case), save, and force your nexus to sync contacts

Now delete the faulty data, sava, and force sync again.

If that didnt work, do the same but with your google+ profile: re-add faulty data, save, and force sync, then delete it.

I did both of the above, so I'm not exactly sure which method worked

Edit: just remembered there was one other thing i did after all of the above:

Go to google plus app on your nexus

Click "settings" and uncheck the contacts syncing.

The old phone number was removed at this point. And turning sync back on did not make it reappear

Hope that helped!

Comment: I haven't thought about this question in a while, and I just went and looked and my ME contact was magically correct (all the crappy old email addresses were gone); who knows what happened.  But I'm still marking this as Best Answer because you put a lot of effort into a specific answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I posted my fix on the [Google Mobile Help Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/mobile/WBQm8bOkc_A/swbS3egrefsJ).

I couldn't get the Me profile to update, so I deleted it. There was a warning that it would just be hidden, but after I did it, I couldn't find a way to bring it back. So I created the local profile instead and just entered my email address.

I also did a lot of cleanup using my PC:

I went to Google+ and cleaned up my profile info. I went to Google Contacts and deleted my contact record, then re-created it. The contact record connected to Google+ when I entered my email address.

I disabled contacts syncing for a bunch of apps on my phone, like Twitter and YouMail.

To get the Me profile to connect to Google+ again and pull my profile info, I went to Manage Apps -> All -> Google+ and hit the Clear cache and Clear data buttons. I opened up the Google+ app and connected my account. Then I went back to the Me profile to confirm that it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue.  Open the Google+ app on your phone.  Sign out of Google+ then sign back in again.  Fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks! I tried all the methods above, and none of them works for me. But this works!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, at least for me:

1. Go to the Google+ app on your phone;
2. Go to setting in Google+ app;
3. Click on contacts;
4. Click so the "Keep contacts up to date" check box is selected;
5. Check my local profile (Me).

Comment: Thank you! This helped me fix a [similar issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88076/how-do-i-link-the-my-info-android-local-profile-back-to-my-google-account/).

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely connected to your Google+ account.  I had a blank "me" profile before logging in to Google+, then the fields began to populate after logging in.  Still working on linking the Google+ to my contact in Google Contacts

Comment: I'm sure it is at least partially connected to your Google+ account, but my ME contact still contains email addresses that have never been listed in my G+ profile.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the steps provided by others are not needed.  I had the same problem and did the following:

1. Look at your (ME) in contacts and determine if you are linked to Google+ or Gmail.
2. Open either G+ or GMail in a web browser based on answer #1
3. If Gmail - Open Contacts and fix the information
4. If Google+ - Open your profile and fix the information
5. On your phone (Mine is Galaxy3s (4.0 ICS)) and Settings->Application Manager->Gmail or Google+-> Click Clear Data then Click Clear Cache.
6. Then go to Settings->Accounts and sync->Then click Sync All

And that was it.  The phone was holding onto old data that was deleted on the web and it needed to be sync'd from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I scoured the internet and found that the "ME" profile was actually related to my MAPS application.  I went to settings > applications > MAPS > uninstall updates and this cleared my "ME" profile.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at your [Google contacts data](http://www.google.com/contacts)?  I believe what you see in Android is actually a combination of data coming from a few different sources, so you likely need to fix it upstream.  At least for me, the data I see in my "me" contact coincides with what I see for myself on google.com/contacts.

Comment: Yes. I looked in Google Contacts, and these extra email addresses (which technically once belonged to me, but I don't want in my contact info) are nowhere to be found there.

Comment: As _Will_ said: the **me** contact is a mashup getting information from different interlinked accounts.

Comment: I'd just like to edit it directly, or be able to see its sources of information, since I can't find the "accounts" where these certain email addresses are being pulled from.

Answer (score 2):

I wasted many hours trying to edit the ME account.  Finally, I just deleted it, and then reentered all the information correctly.  It is absurd that there is no help about this matter, or that one cannot edit this contact, which would save a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to rectify this problem.

The problem persists if you have more than one gmail account in your smartphone and all of them linked with Google+. So, this is what I did, step by step:

1. Login to your PRIMARY gmail acount from your desktop and view your Google Contacts.
2. Search within Google Contacts your PRIMARY gmail address. Your own contact should appear, so just add in your mobile phone number. Save this information if Google Contacts hasn't done it automatically.
3. Next, from your phone, go to the Google+ app and sign out from ALL of the accounts that you have signed into.
4. Lastly, sign back in using your PRIMARY gmail account. By this, 'ME' or 'Myself' from your phone's contact list should have the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Note on "me" profile for dual-sim phone users.

The ME profile appears to recognise multiple numbers as "me" at the same time and will override dialing / texts to/from number "a" to number "b", or even to numbers "c" or "d" if you occasionally use a third or fourth sim.

Best advice is to just delete the "Me" profile.  I've not found an advantage to it and it's a constant annoyance.  Particularly annoying when it appears to choose which of your numbers to think is 'me' at random.  Stops me calling my voicemail as it recognises the number I'm ringing as "Me", then decides if I'm ringing "me" (1234...) I really mean "Me" (5678...), overrides the number I've just dialed and conencts me to a different number.  Same issue if I text, it'll overriride the number I entered and send to a different one.  Although it's pretty rare I have occasion to text from one account to another.

Answer (score -2):

Edit your contact on gmail contact first (using your PC) and then
Uninstall google+ from your GT and run it again.
Open profile from google+ application and it will lead you to choose which account you will use for google+, select don't sync when it ask to sync google+.