# How do I link the "My Info" Android local profile back to my Google+ account?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, privacy

My issue is similar to having a ME profile (it is in a section called ME), but not the same. None of the answers to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17320/how-to-edit-the-me-contact) worked for me. I believe the principle difference is that **I cannot delete** the "My Info" profile. This profile originally did not have my name or email address anywhere in it. It had my phone number listed twice, both with the "Mobile" category, and both 11 digits long (with the leading 1).

My other problem is that the answers say that I should reinput the "faulty data", but I have no faulty data. The data is correct, just listed twice. Is it possible to merge this account or get it recognized as the Google+ profile?

Comment: Exact same for me! I looked again through all of the solutions in the link you listed. I had missed [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/87717/80882 "this") suggestion, which worked for me! I hope it works for you as well. -Mike

Comment: Thanks! I had to do a few extra steps to get it working, but I outlined it in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer originally from here: [How to edit the "ME" contact?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17320/how-to-edit-the-me-contact/87717#87717)

1. Open Google+ on your phone.
2. Go into Settings / Your Name youremail@google.com / Contacts.
3. Check "Keep contacts up to date".
4. Go into Settings / Sync / Google.
5. Disable Contacts Sync. Wait a few seconds, re-enable it.
6. Wait a few more seconds, and the My Info entry should now have a Google+ connection.