# How to set a Contact as "Me"?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use existing contact for “Me” in Ice Cream Sandwich](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17159/use-existing-contact-for-me-in-ice-cream-sandwich)

I have a contact for myself with LOADS of info (websites, phone numbers, emails, etc.) and my new Galaxy S3 created a separate "ME" contact that's totally empty. How do I set my old contact as me?

Simple question, simple answer [hopefully].